# How fix when cmd prints command instead of run it?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, chef

I am trying to automate chef setup for windows. So I wrote `.bat` according to [this](http://docs.chef.io/plugin_knife_windows.html):

```
call winrm quickconfig -q
call winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}
call winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}
call winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
call winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
call netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" profile=public protocol=tcp localport=5985 remoteip=localsubnet new remoteip=any
```

So I saved this into `winrm.bat` and run. But console prints forever:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>winrm quickconfig -q
```

If remove `call` command from all line result is the same. Also if I remove first line `call winrm quickconfig -q` result is:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}
```

I pay you attention that it print these line forever, not one line. But when I open console and manually copy and paste commands one by one everything works.

What is wrong? How to "enable" these command run from `.bat` file?

Cmd is running from Windows Server 2008 x64 SP2. System has been just installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your batch file is called `winrm.bat` and you call (with or without `call` command) `winrm` ... probably you have your batch file calling himself.

The easiest solution is to change the batch file name